# Asynchronous Webscraping with beautiful soup, grequests

Tags: python, asynchronous, web-scraping, grequests

I am trying to webscrape some information from a list of urls, and would like to do it asynchronously to save time. I am able to get the information I would like when I do so synchronously, and the relevant part of that code is essentially this:

```
links = [...] #list of links

for link in links:

   source_race = requests.get(link).text
   soup_race = BeautifulSoup(source_race,'lxml')

   contestant_names = []
   for contestants in soup_race.find_all('div',attrs={'data-automation-id':'racecard-outcome-name'}):
      contestant_names.append(contestants.text.replace('\xa0',' '))
```

This returns me a list of contestent names, which is exactly what I want.

Now when I try to do this asynchronously, I am testing it in a preliminary stage using the print fucntion, like so:

```
reqs = (grequests.get(link) for link in links)
resp = grequests.map(reqs)

for r in resp:
   soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
   results = soup.find_all('div',attrs={'data-automation-id':'racecard-outcome-name'})
   print(results)
```

but I am not getting the text items, I am simply getting an entire list of all of those specifics  on that page. The output looks like (I could not capture the entire output, but it is a long list, containing all of the information I want, but I am unable to pull out the specific text items I want, which I have circled, which are just names and a number in brackets):

[image: Portion of the output]

[image: second potion of the output]

when I try to put `print(results.text)`, I am presented with the following error:

[image: first error message]

when I change my above code to `find` instead of `find_all`, and use `print(results.text)` I get exactly as I would expect (and would like), which is:

[image: one correct output]

I just need a way to have all the runner names printed out.

I am brand new to asynchronous webscraping (and webscraping in general), so I am sorry if any of this is unclear.

Comment: You need to use asyncio for this.

Comment: Thanks for this. I did some research on this and have gotten it to work.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have gotten myself temporarily banned from accessing the website due to the quick fire nature of the requests.

It seems I will need to rotate through a bunch of IP addresses to solve this problem. would something like:

`conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(local_addr=('127.0.0.1', 0), loop=loop)`
`async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=conn) as session:`

(obviously with a list of randomly chosen IP addresses) be the right path to take?

Comment: @TNoms did you try it out and what was the outcome?

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiprocessing 10 links executed asynchronous.
My pseudo code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def scrape(url):
   source_race = requests.get(url).text
   soup_race = BeautifulSoup(source_race,'lxml')

   contestant_names = []
   for contestants in soup_race.find_all('div',attrs={'data-automation-id':'racecard-outcome-name'}):
      contestant_names.append(contestants.text.replace('\xa0',' '))

links = []
p = Pool(10)
p.map(scrape, links)
p.terminate()
p.join()
```